A group of order 2015 has a normal subgroup of order 155.
I am reviewing an old qual problem (see title). I know that if $|G|=2015$, there are unique and hence normal subgroups of order 13 and 31. I also know that if $H,K$ are subgroups of $G$ and $K$ is normal, then $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$. Therefore, letting $P_{31}$ be the unique Sylow-31 subgroup and $P_5$ be any Sylow-5 subgroup, $P_{31}P_5$ is a subgroup of $G$. Since $|P_{31}\cap P_5|=1$ and $|HK|=|H||K|/(|H\cap K|)$, $|P_{31}P_5|=155$. I need to show this subgroup is normal.
I seem to remember there being an approach to a similar problem which would play off the number of Sylow-5 subgroups of $P_{31}P_5$. (Showed there was a unique Sylow-5 and somehow finished from there). In this case, however, even if there are 31 Sylow-5 subgroups in $P_{31}P_5$, we only use up $4\cdot 31=124$ elements. This leaves plenty of room for the unique Sylow subgroup of order 31. How can I finish this problem?
Edit: I think I've made some more progress:
Suppose $H$ is some other subgroup of $G$ of order $155$. Then $H/P_{31} \leqslant G/P_{31}$. Since $|G/P_{31}|=5\cdot 13$, there is a unique Sylow 5 subgroup in $G/P_{31}$ and therefore a unique Sylow 5 subgroup in $H/P_{31}$ and even better, $H/P_{31}\cong Q_5$ where $Q_5$ is some Sylow-5 subgroup of $G$. What to do from here?
I think this implies that $H\cong P_{31}Q_5$. If this is true, then I think $H=P_{31}Q_5\cong P_{31}P_5$. This implies the subgroup of order 155 is unique and hence normal. Is this correct?

Consider the quotient $Q=G/P_{31}$. It has order $65=5\cdot 13$. Let $P$ be a $5$-Sylow subgroup of $Q$. It is normal. Now take the full pre-image of $P$ in $G$, that is $\{g\in G\mid P_{31}g\in Q\}$. It has order $5\cdot 31$ and is normal.

Thanks for the response! Why do we need to consider the pre-image?

Because subgroups of a factor group are not subgroups of the original group, their pre-image is.
